# Fullscreen 3 Column Layout with centered Content in each column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to create a Layout similar to a fullscreen carousel but without images, just styled text.

My approach so far:

[bootply - 3 column content centered](http://www.bootply.com/S9j7L3m2Hi)

**Problem 1:** media-left and media-right should be of full window height.

**Problem 2:** media-left and media-right should reach to the content, the content should only be as width as its content is.

**Problem 3:** The Labels 'left' and 'right' should be in the center of the left/ right side.

*In other words:* The center content is always in the center of the screen and uses the minimal space to the left and right, the left and right columns use the rest of the space and center their content too.

The goal is that the previous and next area use the maximum space on the left/ right.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Muff

Comment: use bootstrap 4  with flex boxes
or flex box without bootstrap , there is no gain to use bootstrap

Comment: @ErickBoileau thanks - i got a little further, see the [sequel topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889902/3-column-flex-layout-middle-column-only-as-width-as-its-content)

Comment: The question was answered in the my Sequel post: [Sequel Post with Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875797/fullscreen-3-column-layout-with-centered-content-in-each-column)

Comment: yes flex is a good choice