# 3 Column Flex Layout - Middle Column only as width as it's content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My fiddle so far:

```css
.fill-height-or-more {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.fill-height-or-more > div {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items : center;
}

.some-area > div {
  padding: 1rem;
}
.some-area > div:nth-child(1) {
  background: #88cc66;
}
.some-area > div:nth-child(2) {
  background: #79b5d2;
}
.some-area > div:nth-child(3) {
  background: #8cbfd9;
}
.some-area > div h1, .some-area > div h2 {
  margin: 0 0 0.2rem 0;
}
.some-area > div p {
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="some-area fill-height-or-more">
  <div>
      <h1>LEFT</h1>

  </div>
  <div>
      <h2>Two</h2>
      <p>This Column should</p>
      <p>only be as width as</p>
      <p>its content.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
      <h2>RIGHT</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

This post is a sequel to my  [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875797/fullscreen-3-column-layout-with-centered-content-in-each-column).

**Quest 1:** I'd like the middle columns to be only as width as its content. The left and right column should then equaly fill the rest of the space so that the middle column always stays in the middle.

Thanks in advance for hour help!

Muff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `flex: 1` to `left` and `right` divs or in your case [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/651/)

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}
.content > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.left,
.right {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
}
.middle {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">Lorem</div>
  <div class="middle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="right">lorem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This version has the middle content/ text overlapping. The middle column should always be as wide as its content and the left and right column should assimilate.

Comment: What do you mean by text overlapping? Does text in middle column should stay in one line?

Comment: Yes the text should stay in one line but the Column Width is not adapting.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! THANKS!!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/drcLepv8/1/)?
You should do:

```
.some-area > div:nth-child(2) {
  background: #79b5d2;
  align-self: center;
}
```

If you want to change the [width](https://jsfiddle.net/drcLepv8/8/) you should do:

```
.some-area > div:nth-child(2) {
      background: #79b5d2;
      flex: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Just like your second example but without breaking the text. I tried using display:block for the text but i wraps anyway.

Comment: Then you should add something like: `flex: 0 0 auto;` It should keep your text ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a fixed width and no shrink or grow to that element by adding (for example) `flex: 0 0 150px;` to its CSS.

```css
.fill-height-or-more {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.fill-height-or-more > div {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items : center;
}

.some-area > div {
  padding: 1rem;
}
.some-area > div:nth-child(1) {
  background: #88cc66;
}
.some-area > div:nth-child(2) {
  background: #79b5d2;
  flex: 0 0 150px;

}
.some-area > div:nth-child(3) {
  background: #8cbfd9;
}
.some-area > div h1, .some-area > div h2 {
  margin: 0 0 0.2rem 0;
}
.some-area > div p {
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="some-area fill-height-or-more">
  <div>
      <h1>LEFT</h1>

  </div>
  <div>
      <h2>Two</h2>
      <p>This Column should</p>
      <p>only be as width as</p>
      <p>its content.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
      <h2>RIGHT</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could play with the sizes of your 3 div's by doing for example so:

```
.some-area > div:nth-child(1) {
background: #88cc66;
flex: .4;
}

.some-area > div:nth-child(2) {
background: #79b5d2;
flex: .2;
align-self: center;

}
.some-area > div:nth-child(3) {
 background: #8cbfd9;
 flex: .4;
}
```

The left and right div would be twice as big, I'm not sure though if that is what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This would be a nice fallback approach in combination with media queries.

Comment: Yeah, it's A solution, but probably not the best one. Have you made any progress by the way?